# Parse nested array from JSON using NewtonSoft Missing Items

Tags: json, vb.net

I have a JSON result returned from an API call (from Domoticz home control software) that I am trying to parse in VB.NET web application using Newtonsoft. It look slike:

```
{
   "ActTime" : 1555786428,
   "AstrTwilightEnd" : "21:22",
   "AstrTwilightStart" : "05:38",
   "CivTwilightEnd" : "20:23",
   "CivTwilightStart" : "06:36",
   "DayLength" : "12:59",
   "NautTwilightEnd" : "20:52",
   "NautTwilightStart" : "06:07",
   "ServerTime" : "2019-04-20 14:53:48",
   "SunAtSouth" : "13:05",
   "Sunrise" : "07:00",
   "Sunset" : "19:59",
   "app_version" : "4.9700",
   "result" : [
      {
         "AddjMulti" : 1.0,
         "AddjMulti2" : 1.0,
         "AddjValue" : 0.0,
         "AddjValue2" : 0.0,
         "BatteryLevel" : 255,
         "CustomImage" : 0,
         "Data" : "75.7 F",
         "Description" : "",
         "Favorite" : 1,
         "HardwareID" : 2,
         "HardwareName" : "mygateway1",
         "HardwareType" : "MySensors Gateway with MQTT interface",
         "HardwareTypeVal" : 92,
         "HaveTimeout" : false,
         "ID" : "6600",
         "LastUpdate" : "2019-04-20 14:53:47",
         "Name" : "Dining Room",
         "Notifications" : "false",
         "PlanID" : "0",
         "PlanIDs" : [ 0 ],
         "Protected" : false,
         "ShowNotifications" : true,
         "SignalLevel" : "-",
         "SubType" : "LaCrosse TX3",
         "Temp" : 75.700000000000003,
         "Timers" : "false",
         "Type" : "Temp",
         "TypeImg" : "temperature",
         "Unit" : 0,
         "Used" : 1,
         "XOffset" : "0",
         "YOffset" : "0",
         "idx" : "3"
      },
      {
         "AddjMulti" : 1.0,
         "AddjMulti2" : 1.0,
         "AddjValue" : 0.0,
         "AddjValue2" : 0.0,
         "BatteryLevel" : 255,
         "CustomImage" : 0,
         "Data" : "72.5 F",
         "Description" : "",
         "Favorite" : 1,
         "HardwareID" : 2,
         "HardwareName" : "mygateway1",
         "HardwareType" : "MySensors Gateway with MQTT interface",
         "HardwareTypeVal" : 92,
         "HaveTimeout" : true,
         "ID" : "6500",
         "LastUpdate" : "2018-12-01 14:51:37",
         "Name" : "Living Room",
         "Notifications" : "false",
         "PlanID" : "0",
         "PlanIDs" : [ 0 ],
         "Protected" : false,
         "ShowNotifications" : true,
         "SignalLevel" : "-",
         "SubType" : "LaCrosse TX3",
         "Temp" : 72.5,
         "Timers" : "false",
         "Type" : "Temp",
         "TypeImg" : "temperature",
         "Unit" : 0,
         "Used" : 1,
         "XOffset" : "0",
         "YOffset" : "0",
         "idx" : "2"
      },
      {
         "AddjMulti" : 1.0,
         "AddjMulti2" : 1.0,
         "AddjValue" : 0.0,
         "AddjValue2" : 0.0,
         "BatteryLevel" : 255,
         "Chill" : 69.799999999999997,
         "CustomImage" : 0,
         "Data" : "341.00;NNW;66;78;21.0;21.0",
         "Description" : "",
         "Direction" : 341.0,
         "DirectionStr" : "NNW",
         "Favorite" : 1,
         "Gust" : "17.4",
         "HardwareID" : 3,
         "HardwareName" : "DarkSky",
         "HardwareType" : "DarkSky (Weather Lookup)",
         "HardwareTypeVal" : 25,
         "HaveTimeout" : false,
         "ID" : "0001",
         "LastUpdate" : "2019-04-20 14:50:51",
         "Name" : "DSwind",
         "Notifications" : "false",
         "PlanID" : "0",
         "PlanIDs" : [ 0 ],
         "Protected" : false,
         "ShowNotifications" : true,
         "SignalLevel" : "-",
         "Speed" : "14.8",
         "SubType" : "TFA",
         "Temp" : 69.799999999999997,
         "Timers" : "false",
         "Type" : "Wind",
         "TypeImg" : "wind",
         "Unit" : 0,
         "Used" : 1,
         "XOffset" : "0",
         "YOffset" : "0",
         "forecast_url" : "aHR0cHM6Ly9kYXJrc2t5Lm5ldC8jL2YvMjguMzM1NTY3JTJDLTgyLjY3MTY2MQ==",
         "idx" : "5"
      },
      {
         "AddjMulti" : 1.0,
         "AddjMulti2" : 1.0,
         "AddjValue" : 0.0,
         "AddjValue2" : 0.0,
         "Barometer" : 1016,
         "BatteryLevel" : 255,
         "CustomImage" : 0,
         "Data" : "69.8 F, 43 %, 1016 hPa",
         "Description" : "",
         "DewPoint" : "46.30",
         "Favorite" : 0,
         "Forecast" : 1,
         "ForecastStr" : "Sunny",
         "HardwareID" : 3,
         "HardwareName" : "DarkSky",
         "HardwareType" : "DarkSky (Weather Lookup)",
         "HardwareTypeVal" : 25,
         "HaveTimeout" : false,
         "Humidity" : 43,
         "HumidityStatus" : "Comfortable",
         "ID" : "0001",
         "LastUpdate" : "2019-04-20 14:50:51",
         "Name" : "DStemp",
         "Notifications" : "false",
         "PlanID" : "0",
         "PlanIDs" : [ 0 ],
         "Protected" : false,
         "ShowNotifications" : true,
         "SignalLevel" : "-",
         "SubType" : "THB1 - BTHR918, BTHGN129",
         "Temp" : 69.799999999999997,
         "Timers" : "false",
         "Type" : "Temp + Humidity + Baro",
         "TypeImg" : "temperature",
         "Unit" : 1,
         "Used" : 1,
         "XOffset" : "0",
         "YOffset" : "0",
         "forecast_url" : "aHR0cHM6Ly9kYXJrc2t5Lm5ldC8jL2YvMjguMzM1NTY3JTJDLTgyLjY3MTY2MQ==",
         "idx" : "4"
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK",
   "title" : "Devices"
}
```

I have two classes:

```
Public Class DomoticzDevices_Rootobject
    Public Property ActTime As Integer
    Public Property AstrTwilightEnd As String
    Public Property AstrTwilightStart As String
    Public Property CivTwilightEnd As String
    Public Property CivTwilightStart As String
    Public Property DayLength As String
    Public Property NautTwilightEnd As String
    Public Property NautTwilightStart As String
    Public Property ServerTime As String
    Public Property SunAtSouth As String
    Public Property Sunrise As String
    Public Property Sunset As String
    Public Property app_version As String
    Public Property result As List(Of DomoticzDevices_result)
    Public Property status As String
    Public Property title As String
End Class

Public Class DomoticzDevices_result
    Public Property Data As String
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property Favorite As Integer
    Public Property LastUpdate As String
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property PlanID As String
    Public Property PlanIDs() As Integer
    Public Property _Protected As Boolean
    Public Property Status As String
    Public Property Type As String
    Public Property TypeImg As String
    Public Property UsedByCamera As Boolean
    Public Property XOffset As Object
    Public Property YOffset As Object
    Public Property idx As String
    Public Property AddjMulti As Single
    Public Property AddjMulti2 As Single
    Public Property AddjValue As Single
    Public Property AddjValue2 As Single
    Public Property BatteryLevel As Integer
    Public Property CustomImage As Integer
    Public Property HardwareID As Integer
    Public Property HardwareName As String
    Public Property HardwareType As String
    Public Property HardwareTypeVal As Integer
    Public Property HaveTimeout As Boolean
    Public Property ID As String
    Public Property Notifications As String
    Public Property ShowNotifications As Boolean
    Public Property SignalLevel As String
    Public Property SubType As String
    Public Property Temp As Single
    Public Property Timers As String
    Public Property Unit As Integer
    Public Property Used As Integer
    Public Property UVI As String
    Public Property forecast_url As String
    Public Property Rain As String
    Public Property RainRate As String
    Public Property Chill As Single
    Public Property Direction As Single
    Public Property DirectionStr As String
    Public Property Gust As String
    Public Property Speed As String
    Public Property Barometer As Integer
    Public Property DewPoint As String
    Public Property Forecast As Integer
    Public Property ForecastStr As String
    Public Property Humidity As Integer
    Public Property HumidityStatus As String
    Public Property SwitchTypeVal As Integer
    Public Property Visibility As Single
    Public Property Image As String
    Public Property SensorType As Integer
    Public Property SensorUnit As String
    Public Property CameraIdx As String
    Public Property DimmerType As String
    Public Property HaveDimmer As Boolean
    Public Property HaveGroupCmd As Boolean
    Public Property IsSubDevice As Boolean
    Public Property Level As Integer
    Public Property LevelInt As Integer
    Public Property MaxDimLevel As Integer
    Public Property StrParam1 As String
    Public Property StrParam2 As String
    Public Property SwitchType As String
End Class
```

The code to parse/access looks like:

```
Public Function ListOfDevices(Optional ByRef DeviceType As String = "all") As DomoticzDevices_Rootobject
    Dim result As New DomoticzDevices_Rootobject
    Dim resp As HttpWebResponse
    Dim PathToService As String = _EndPointURL & "/json.htm?type=devices&filter=" + DeviceType + "&used=true&order=Name"
    Dim req As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(PathToService), HttpWebRequest)
    req.Accept = "application/json"
    req.Method = "GET"
    req.PreAuthenticate = True

    Try
        resp = TryCast(req.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Dim resultAPI As New CallRestOutput

        If (Not resp Is Nothing) Then
            Using responseStream As New IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream())
                If (Not responseStream Is Nothing) Then
                    resultAPI.Output = responseStream.ReadToEnd()
                End If
            End Using

            Try
                JsonConvert.PopulateObject(resultAPI.Output, result)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw
            End Try
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try

    Return result
End Function
```

What is happening is that all items in the `DomoticzDevices_Rootobject` except for `result`, `status`, and `title` are populated. I am not sure why they are not. The items in the root response are system stats. What I really need are the items in the `result` array which I will use up-stream on a front end.

What am I missing?

Comment: Some properties are missing in some of the objects. You could decorate those properties with `NullValueHandling.Ignore`. For example, the `forecast_url` property: `<JsonProperty("forecast_url", NullValueHandling:=NullValueHandling.Ignore)> Public Property ForecastUrl As String`. This should allow to deserialize the objects in full, thus not skipping `status` and `title`.

Comment: The `_Protected` property is wrong, it should be named `[Protected]`. Or decorated.

Comment: I commend both of you! Adding the `[Protected]` instead of `_Protected` worked. And i needed to hand non-existent fields. All useful fields now return.

Comment: That's just me ;) Another thing, some non-string ignorable/null-handled properties should be declared as nullable. For example, `Barometer` should be `Public Property Barometer As Long?`, `Chill` `-> Public Property Chill As Double?` etc.